# how to center layout to vertical in android through java code?

Tags: android

friends,

i want to set android:layout_centerVertical="true" property of layout
through java code of an image.

can any one guide me how to achieve this. here is my code.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

params.height = (int)totalHeight;

img.setLayoutParams(params);
```

i have tried using setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER) but no use.

any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong but it sounds like you are trying to set the alignment (or positional orientation) of an image inside of a layout? To do that you need to set the gravity property of the layout containing the View you align.

```
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);

    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.TOP);
    layout.addView(imageView);
```

In this example I'm programmatically adding an image to a RelativeLayout in my layout resource, adding an ImageView, and aligning it so it will be placed at the top, vertical center position.

Answer (score 50):

Try this Code..

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
          ((int) LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, (int) LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);

img.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: I prefer this over the accepted answer because it doesn't affect any other subviews of the parent view.

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer in RelativeLayout!

Answer (score 2):

In the new SDK there's no `Gravity.VERTICAL_CENTER`, but maybe you could set this with 
`layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER)`.