# Android: Set an imageview to the bottom of my relativelayout

Tags: android, android-layout

```
 RelativeLayout overlay = new RelativeLayout(this);
            addContentView(overlay, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, px));
            overlay.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);


            border = new ImageView(this);
            border.setImageResource(R.drawable.featured_bar);
            border.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            overlay.addView(border);
```

I would like to get **my border imageview to sit at the bottom of my relativelayout**, and **`programmatically`** or course.

Basically, I want my decorative border to be at a certain position relative to the resolution, and since I do not know how to position using x y values, I've come to this method.

Comment: You can take a help from this [answer][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053864/how-to-center-layout-to-vertical-in-android-through-java-code

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
overlay.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191099/how-to-set-relativelayout-layout-params-in-code-not-in-xml) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305395/laying-out-views-in-relativelayout-programmatically)