# Setting "Wrap Content" to a view programmatically

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Is it possible to set Wrap Content Identifier int?  Will the following code work?

```
EditText ET = new EditText(getActivity());
ET.setWidth(WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you should do something like that:

```
EditText editTextView = new EditText(getActivity());
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
editTextView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it via layout params:
Add this line to your code

```
ET.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: And so is permissible?

``LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    EditText ET = new EditText(getActivity());
    ET.setId(1);
    ET.setHint("Your name");
    ET.setInputType(0x00000061);
    ET.setLayoutParams(params);
    ET.setPadding(40,20,40,20);
    layout.addView(ET);``

Comment: yes,I think you can use that. Which part do you have a doubt about?

Comment: All serene! Have you happen to know is about as do `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` programmatically?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053864/how-to-center-layout-to-vertical-in-android-through-java-code you can find it there.

Comment: `ET.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL );` It did not help.

Comment: Too :(, See image please (http://cs617126.vk.me/v617126773/d164/NRrsR43SF5M.jpg). Why `.addRule` is lit?

Comment: you should use params.addRule, not ET.addRule